# AngularJS generate HTML template with ng-click="function(arg)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to generate an HTML templaye from `AngularJS directive` but I'm not able to pass any object into a function within one of the generated elements. This is my directive:

```
app.directive('listObject', function($compile){
  return {
    scope : {
      obj : "="
    },
    controller: "httpPostController",
    link : function(scope, element) {

      scope.elementTree = null;

      //recursivly generate the object output
      scope.printObject = function (field, content) {
        if (field){
          content = "<div>"
          if (field.isRequired){
            content += "<p>" + field.name + "*:</p>";
          } else {
            content += "<p>" + field.name + ":</p>";
          }

          if (field.isEnum){
            content += '<select ng-model="createEntityResource[field.name]" ng-change="getCreateEntityAsText()" class="form-control">' + 
                       '<option></option>' +
                       '<option ng-repeat="enumValue in field.enumValues" label={{enumValue.name}}>{{enumValue.ordinal}}</option>' +
                       '</select>';
          } else if (field.restResourceName) {
            content += '<button type="button" ng-click="loadResourceFieldsForField(field)">Create new</button>';
            //                           content += "<p>"+i+""+scope.printObject(field)+"</p>";
          } else {
           content += '<input type="text" ng-model="createEntityResource[' + field.name + ']" ng-change="getCreateEntityAsText()"' + 
                      'class="form-control" placeholder="{{parseClassName(field.type)}}">';
          }
          content+="</div>";
          return content;
        }

      };

      scope.refresh = function (){
        if(scope.elementTree){
          scope.elementTree.remove();   
        }
        //generate the html into a string
        var content = scope.printObject(scope.obj, content);
        //make elements out of a string
        scope.elementTree = angular.element(content);
        compiled = $compile(scope.elementTree);
        element.append(scope.elementTree);
        compiled(scope);
      };

      scope.refresh();

    }
  };
});
```

When I create a `<button>` element - I give it a `ng-click` function. The function is called and works fine, except that the param it is passed (field) is always `undefined`.

Does anyone know how to pass object into function within an `AngularJS directive`?

Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

P.S. I tried to split the definition of the button to :

```
'<button type="button" ng-click="loadResourceFieldsForField(' + field + ')">Create new</button>';
```

but this does not seem work, AngularJS argues about [Object object] being passed to a function.

P.P.S I also tried to make it according to documentation which says:

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an
>   expression and to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map
>   of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For
>   example, if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify
>   Blockquote
>   the amount value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

So it looks like this, but `field` is still undefined:

```
'<button type="button" ng-click="loadResourceFieldsForField({field: field})">Create new</button>';
```

Comment: Create a fiddle for it...

Comment: Why don't you use template or tmplateUrl option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my `printObject` algorithm worked great :)

```
`<button type="button" ng-click="loadResourceFieldsForField(' + field + ')">Create new</button>`
```

The problem here is: You are generating a string.
And you print your object into the string. This will call `toString` within the object and won't do what you want to do. It will just print `"loadResourceFieldsForField([Object])"`

```
`<button type="button" ng-click="loadResourceFieldsForField({field: field})">Create new</button>`
```

The `field` property in the string doesn't have any reference to your param `field` in the method. 
Within `$compile`: angularjs will search for a variable `field` within the scope and won't find any.

You have to place this field in the scope, to make this work as aspected. But it seems not like a easy job there.

I would try this:

[$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) in each `printObject` with an own [$scope.$new](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) containing the `field` variable.